# How to Find Parent Child Combination at each Iteration of Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

**Parent Child Combination at each Iteration of Array**

I am Too Confused and Stuck too not able to figure out what can be done.

Here is my Problem

If i have 10 Nodes(Can Be N for Example i am Mentioning as 10) where if one loop selected at One Time and that Combination Nodes cannot be selected again,and Cross Loops Cannot Be selected too.

They can Have[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7)(8,8)(9,9)(10,10)] self loops combinations, two Node loops combinations with Self Loop Included too [(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7,8)(9,10)] Or [(2,3)(5,6)(9,10),(1,1)....] and 3 node Loops with Child Self Loop and 2 Node Loops with Self Loops too and 4 node Loops with Child 2 Nodes or Child Self Node loop and these goes on

Parent Child Combination is the Most Deadliest Part:[(1,5)(2,4)(3,3)(6,10)(7,9)(8,8)]

So I Just want to write logic as In the Above arrays i would get Each One At a time where i push them into array

```
Eg: In 10 Nodes if user Selects 2 and 4 i would set the array as follows

[(startIndex:2,endIndex:4,depthOfLoop:1)]

Now he cannot touch 2 and 4 again or internal 3 node to Which forms a cross Loop

if the user selects 6 and 9 then i need to match the before array object 

this 6 and 9 goes into the newStartIndex and newEndIndex
As per My Assumptions generally i would get 4 Comparisions

for ChildLoop:-(newStartIndex>startIndex && newEndIndex<endIndex)
for ParentLoop:-(newStartIndex<startIndex && newEndIndex>endIndex)
for SameCategoryLoop:-((newStartIndex<startIndex && newEndIndex<startIndex)/(newStartIndex>endIndex&& newEndIndex>endIndex))

for SameCategoryLoop Previous Array DepthOfLoop Becomes same to the newArray which is 6,9 is checked with 2,4 and goes into ((newStartIndex>endIndex&& newEndIndex>endIndex)) then My Array would be as follows

[(startIndex:2,endIndex:4,depthOfLoop:1)(startIndex:6,endIndex:9,depthOfLoop:1)]
```

Then in next Iteration if User Selects 1 and 5 i need to verify this newStartIndex and newEndIndex with above two Objects startIndex and endIndex and i need to decide the depthOfLoop

```
> It comes into two category. 
> One is ParentLoop:-(newStartIndex<startIndex && newEndIndex>endIndex) based on (2,4) and 
> Another is SameCategoryLoop ((newStartIndex<startIndex &&newEndIndex<startIndex) based on (6,9). 
> Now i need to switch between depthOfLoops too.
```

While Pushing into Array i need to find the Parent child combinations for each one iteration which need to verify with all Values in the Array Object.

This is the main issue which i am facing please suggest with the Logic which could be helpfull for me

**Please help.**

Comment: Value simplicity over complexity if possible. What is the use case for this kind of function?

Comment: This is to use the nested loop functions based on the Parent and Child combinations   if my array got this loop [(1,5)(2,4)]  then my iterations for parent for eg: 3 loops and for child 4 loops then i need to iterate as shown below[123423423423451234234234234512342342342345] nested loop functionality to be maintained based on the parent child combination